# desktop development language compiled binary or scripting language (windows)?

Tags: python, windows, delphi, lua, desktop-application

Does anyone use a scripting language only solution to produce a binary (.exe) to produce a commercial desktop application for windows or mac? e.g. Java, python etc. If so how do you distribute your app and does using a scripting language cause any problems with the installation?

I'm asking about users that can download an application and install it, they don't know about setting path variables, or changing there JAVA_HOME. The assumption for the PC are users with a consumer PC with windows (XP/Vista/7), not power users. (Or alternatively a mac type solution would be interesting to hear about to)

Comment: "That wasn't really my question"?  What **is** your question?  It's hard to figure out.  Your question says Windows.  Your comment says "cross platform".  Please **update** your question to be one, consistent question.  Please **focus**.  We can't *guess* what your question is.  You must state it clearly.

Comment: Note that JAVA_HOME usually is not for the JRE (Java Runtime Environment) but for the JDK location, so it is only used by the developer's environment, not the user of the compiled application. So Java end users do not have to configure this environment variable. p.s. Java is not a scripting language.

Comment: I would not call Java a "scripting language only". Usually a "scripting language" is one where source code (or at least its compact representation) is parsed and executed at runtime. Java goes anyway through a compilation step, although not directly to machine code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this in a couple ways.  One was to use Python and [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/), and the other was to use [Idle](http://idle.thomaslauer.com/), a Lua-based "compilable" language, using [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) to create installers.

I have had no problems with either, though I haven't used Idle for anything of any significant complexity --- its main advantage is the small size of the executable produced.  With py2exe, you have to be careful to get all the dependencies included in the package, and I recommend testing it thoroughly on a clean installation of Windows before releasing.  For example, when I used PyGTK with py2exe, I had to be very careful to get the theming files included in the package.  It was not evident at first that I had missed them, since PyGTK found them in the installed version on the development machine.

I also had to be careful about installation paths, permissions, and startup directories, as well as licensing of the libraries I used, but that's nothing you wouldn't have to be concerned with in a more traditional compiled language.  Other than the relatively large size of the installer, I've been very happy with py2exe and InnoSetup, and I'd recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone use anything else for shrink wrap apps on windows? e.g. Java, python etc.

Yes. I assume you're not really asking about Java, since that is so wide-spread. I can count quite a few Java applications that *I* use, and I don't operate in the "Enterprise" environment.

There are tools that allow you to ship Python code without shipping actual `.py` files and without needing the to actually have Python installed, so there are solutions for that as well. Since such tools exist I assume people do ship Python applications.

> If so how do you distribute your app and does using a scripting language cause any problems with the installation?

What scripting language?

Comment: I'm aware of the a couple of the to exe solutions (python 2 exe, and I've heard of a java one). I'm wondering if anyone has actually done this - distributed a windows app written only in a scripting language as a commercial product? 

If so were there any problems encountered? e.g. openGL integration, graphics, sql etc. I suppose I'm asking for war stories.

..and if a scripting language was used which one?

Comment: @daven11: "I'm wondering if anyone has actually done this - distributed a windows app written only in a scripting language as a commercial product?"  Why wonder?    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/py2exe seems to cover all possible angles.

Comment: indeed, it is difficult to determine if these are commercial apps, personal apps or internal enterprise apps which I think is adequately stated in my question.

Comment: @daven11: "I think is adequately stated in my question".  Think for a moment.  If folks didn't understand that point, then it can't possibly be "adequately stated".  You **must** clarify that point if you want it to be part of the answers.  Please **update** your question to make it clear, rather than insist that it already is clear.